# how do i use viewFliper to slide bottom to top?

Tags: android, slide, viewflipper

I am using the view flipper to slid up the image but i want to slid up the image vertically bottom to top. In my app want to slid up an image upwards. How can i do that? Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/ its similar to what you want to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.